# trying to get the verification code with get_attribute

Tags: python, selenium

trying to get the verification code from
 `<a title="" class="viewLink title-subject" data-mail-id="63723a414a27be00139787e2">637452 is your Instagram code</a>` with get_attribute

I tryed using get_attribute("name") but it dosent work, please help. and value but dosent work

Comment: where did you get `get_attribute("name")` this? Please post all relevant code.

Comment: The attribute ` data-mail-id="63723a414a27be00139787e2"` is always the same value? Or it does change? Another thing, If you go to your browser devtool and you try to find the element by xpath `//a[@class='viewLink title-subject']`how many results do you get? Is there more than one element?

Comment: The data.mail-id changes and I have no clue how to search for that in the devtool

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.